# Xarray Dataset: how to change NetCDF file 'time' dimension from units of 'hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00' to datetime format?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, multidimensional-array, netcdf, python-xarray

I am having trouble converting the time dimension in an xarray dataset (consisting of NetCDF files) from units of 'hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00' to a datetime format (ex. 2000-01-01 00:00:00).  The Xarray docs have a very similar example, but the recommended fix(shown below) did not work for my dataset.

**I first start by utilizing xarray.open_mfdataset (with decode_times=False on) to load my dataset.

This operation is completed successfully.**

```
dataset =  xr.open_mfdataset(file_list, decode_times=False, data_vars='minimal', coords='minimal', parallel=True)
```

---

`print(dataset)`

`<xarray.Dataset>`
`Dimensions:            (time: 4139, depth: 40, lat: 63, lon: 79)`

`Coordinates:`

- `time               (time) float64 1.403e+05 1.403e+05 ... 1.556e+05`
- `depth              (depth) float64 0.0 2.0 4.0 6.0 ... 3e+03 4e+03 5e+03`
- `lat                (lat) float64 30.0 30.08 30.16 30.24 ... 34.8 34.88 34.96`
- `lon                (lon) float64 -81.28 -81.2 -81.12 ... -75.2 -75.12 -75.04`
- `Data variables:`
- `tau                (time) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1,), meta=np.ndarray>`
- `water_u            (time, depth, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 40, 63, 79),....`

---

`print(dataset.time)`

```
array([140268., 140271., 140274., ..., 155595., 155598., 155601.])

Coordinates:
```

- ```
  time     (time) float64 1.403e+05 1.403e+05 ... 1.556e+05 1.556e+05Attributes:
  ```
- ```
  long_name:    Valid Timeunits:        hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00
  ```
- ```
  time_origin:  2000-01-01 00:00:00
  ```
- ```
  calendar:     gregorian
  ```
- ```
  axis:          T
  ```
- ```
  TNAVO_code:    13
  ```

---

**The xarray docs have an example almost exactly like this, in which they prescribe the simple use of xarray.decode_cf() to manually convert the time dimension from 'hours since...' to a datetime object.**

**However when I use** `xr.decode_cf(dataset)` **, the following error is thrown:**

```
ValueError: invalid reference date for time units: analysis
```

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

---

```
ValueError: unable to decode time units 'hours since analysis' with 'the default calendar'. Try opening your dataset with decode_times=False or installing cftime if it is not installed.
```

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

---

```
ValueError: Failed to decode variable 'tau': unable to decode time units 'hours since analysis' with 'the default calendar'. Try opening your dataset with decode_times=False or installing cftime if it is not installed.
```

**Do I need to install the 'cftime' package to deal with this? Is there a way I can manually work around this in Xarray?**

Thank you

EDIT:

I have found a solution here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469858/17461323

While this solution does work, it is unclear to me why refeeding in the same information that exists within the NetCDF file works.  it seems like a 'hacky' solution.  Is this an xarray issue?

C. Love
FSU Meteorology

Comment: I guess the problem is that the time coordinate specification in your data does not conform to the [CF standard](https://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/cf-conventions.html#time-coordinate). You'll want `unit` instead of `long_name` to be `"hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00"`.